# Keys and values in separate columns, I want to create columns with corresponding values

Tags: python, typeerror, key-value

Sorry for the confusing title! I have the following columns in my dataframe:

```
Column A                         Column B
['Dogs','Cats','Horses']       [0.5,0.25,0.25]    
['Dogs']                       [1.0]   
['Cats','Horses']             [0.75,0.25]
```

And the output I would like is:

```
Dogs                        Cats                        Horses
0.5                         0.25                        0.25   
1.0                         0                           0  
0                           0.75                        0.25
```

Thank you in advance! :)

I tried the following code:

```
keys = set([key for row in df['column_a'] for key in row])

for key in keys:
    df[key] = 0.0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for key, value in zip(row['column_a'], row['column_b']):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for demography, score in zip(key, value):
                df.at[i, demography] = score
        else:
            df.at[i, key] = value

df.drop(columns=['column_a', 'column_b'], inplace=True)
```

and got an error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 2):

It's simple pandas oneliner:

```py
>>> df.explode(list(df.columns)).pivot(columns="Column A", values="Column B").fillna(0)
Column A  Cats  Dogs  Horses
0         0.25   0.5    0.25
1         0.00   1.0    0.00
2         0.75   0.0    0.25
```

`explode` will explode in parallel all columns, then `pivot` will reshape the result.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Unfortunately this approach gave me almost 50 columns of all the possible variants, for example ['Dogs','Cats','Horses'], ['Dogs','Cats'], ['Dogs']. Do you know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: @lunapie can you share result of `df.to_dict()` - your `Column A` is likely a string, or some array-like object that doesn't work smoothly with `explode`, also what version of pandas you're using ?

Comment: Thanks, for getting back to me, I get result {'column_a': {0: "['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Birds', 'Lizards']",
  1: "['Dogs']",
  2: "['Horses', 'Bunnies', 'Cats', 'Dogs', 'Birds']",
  3: "['Dogs', 'Cats', 'Birds']",...
...},
 'column_b': {0: '[0.66, 0.29, 0.02, 0.03]',
  1: '[1.0]',
  2: '[0.7, 0.16, 0.13, 0.01, 0.01]',
  3: '[0.85, 0.14, 0.0]',
  4: '[0.87, 0.09, 0.03, 0.0]',,
  ...}}

The dataset is 28k rows. Pandas version 2.0.3.

Comment: you see - it's string - I'd look into upstream how you acquire this dataframe in the first place, quick and dirty fix to it should be: `df = df.applymap(eval)`

Comment: That gives me error: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
The data is for a project, I got it like this and am not sure how I can work with it :/

Comment: `df = df.applymap(lambda x: eval(x or "[]"))`